# Using the IF control flow function to return rows based on what they are

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have this code:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.auction_id) AS amount, a.owner_id
FROM 
    auctions AS a
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON a.owner_id=u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN winners AS w ON a.auction_id=w.auction_id
WHERE 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(a.start_time) BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-31 23:59:59' 
AND 
    a.owner_id IN (100012,100027,100030,100063,100065)
AND 
    a.active=1 
AND 
    a.approved=1 
AND 
    a.is_relisted_item=0 
AND 
    a.is_draft=0    
GROUP BY 
    a.owner_id
HAVING 
    amount > 4;
```

What I want to do is something like the below, but I just don't know how to write it..

If `a.list_in = 'store' AND a.closed=1` then it MUST appear in the winners table to be included in the result set. So basically `w.winner_id` should NOT be NULL in the `winners` table for it to be included as a result.

So basically, if `a.list_in = 'store'` that is fine and should be included, BUT if `a.list_in = 'store' AND a.closed=1` then for it to be included `w.winner_id` can't be NULL.

How can I do this?

Comment: How about `... AND (a.closed = 0 OR w.winner_id IS NOT NULL) ...` ?

Comment: have you tried `WHERE w.winner_id IS NOT NULL`? or am I missing the point?

Comment: @Vatev that won't work because if `a.list_in != 'store'` then it won't get included unless it's in the winners table. Only `a.list_in = 'store'` need to be in the winners table if it's closed.

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer That would only include the results if it was included in the winners table; they only have to be found in the winners table if it's `a.list_in = 'store' AND a.closed=1`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would be obvious enough without writing the entire query. I'm gonna try again: `... (conditions_for_not_in_winners OR (whatever_it_needs_to_be_to_be_in_winners AND w.winner_id IS NOT NULL))...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(a.auction_id) AS amount, a.owner_id
FROM 
    auctions AS a
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON a.owner_id=u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN winners AS w ON a.auction_id=w.auction_id
WHERE 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(a.start_time) BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-31 23:59:59' 
AND 
    a.owner_id IN (100012,100027,100030,100063,100065)
AND 
    a.active=1 
AND 
    a.approved=1 
AND 
    a.is_relisted_item=0 
AND 
    a.is_draft=0 
AND (NOT(a.list_in = 'store' AND a.closed=1 ) OR (w.auction_id IS NOT NULL))   
GROUP BY 
    a.owner_id
HAVING 
    amount > 4;
```

This should work

added an extra condition in where

```
AND (NOT(a.list_in = 'store' AND a.closed=1 ) OR (w.auction_id IS NOT NULL))
```